# Relation between P chart and Chi-square test

Tags: self-study, chi-squared-test, quality-control

P chart checks whether a manufacturing process is in control with respect to the proportion of non confirming items and Chi-square test for homogeneity tests whether several populations are similar or equal or homogeneous in some characteristics. 
How can I establish a relation between the two?

Comment: Could you explain why you think there should be any relationship at all?

Comment: This was a question asked in one of the quality control examination.